# Append extra column value to previous column

Tags: sql, sql-server

SQL Server problem: I want to append extra column value to previous column set:

```
Name1 Roll1   Address1 Name2    Roll2 Address2      Namen  Rolln Addressn 
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
A       1      abc     B         2      bca          C      3      bbv
```

Result set should be like this:

```
   Name Roll Address
   ------------------
    A     1     abc
    B     2     bca 
    C     3     bbv
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A union query is one option here:

```
SELECT Name1 AS Name, Roll1 AS Roll, Address1 AS Address FROM yourTable
UNION ALL
SELECT Name2, Roll2, Address2 FROM yourTable
UNION ALL
SELECT Name3, Roll3, Address3 FROM yourTable;
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to unpivot the data.  In SQL Server, I would recommend `APPLY`:

```
select v.*
from t cross apply
     (values (name1, roll1, address1),
             (name2, roll2, address2),
             (name3, roll3, address3)
     ) v(name, roll, address);
```

This has two advantages over a `union all` approach.  First, it scans the original table only once.  This is not much of a performance gain for a table, but if the "table" is really a view or a complex query, that can be a big win.

Second, the logic is all in one place.  For just selecting columns, this isn't a big deal.  But if you wanted to filter out `null` values of `name`, then you can just add the condition once:  `where v.name is not null`.